# Confused about hex vs utf-8 encoding

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding

Let's take the character ñ ([unicode-table](https://unicode-table.com/en/00F1/)).

When I run `ord('ñ')` I get back `241` - ie its the 241th encoded character.
When I run `hex(ord('ñ'))` I get back `0xf1`, which is the hex value for `241`.

So why when I run `'ñ'.encode('utf-8')` I get back `b'\xc3\xb1'` or `50097` in decimal? Didn't we just confirm that `ñ` is `f1` (hex) or `241` (dec)?

Comment: TL;DR: UTF-8 does not simply encode the Unicode code point value straight to bytes, it’s a little more complicated than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

241 is the unicode codepoint that corresponds to the glyph "LATIN SMALL LETTER N WITH TILDE".  In Python, characters are stored internally as their unicode codepoints, so `ord('ñ')` is 241.

Encodings are mappings of characters to bytes.  Different encodings may or may not use the same bytes to represent the same characters.

```
>>> 'ñ'.encode('utf-8')
b'\xc3\xb1'
>>> 'ñ'.encode('latin-1')
b'\xf1'
>>> 'ñ'.encode('cp1252')
b'\xf1'
>>> 'ñ'.encode('cp1254')
b'\xf1'
>>> 'ñ'.encode('utf-16')
b'\xff\xfe\xf1\x00'
>>> 'ñ'.encode('utf-32')
b'\xff\xfe\x00\x00\xf1\x00\x00\x00'
```

If you call `str.encode()` without providing a target encoding, Python will select the system default - UTF-8 in your case.

To sum up:

- `ord(s)` returns the unicode codepoint for a particular character
- `s.encode('<some encoding>')` returns the bytes mapped to that character in the provided encoding